# Using Expresso store and trying to hardcode weight of UPS shipment

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ups-shipping

I have a large database of products. None of these products have a weight and probably won't have a weight added in for future entries. I do however know what the weight of a shipment will be for all packages.

Is there a way to hard code the weight of the shipment which is passed on to UPS via the UPS shipping module included with Store?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply hard code this in the shipping plugin. You need to remember not to replace this file when you upgrade Store though.

Open `store/libraries/store_shipping/store_shipping_ups.php`, and around line 135 you will find this:

```
// order weight must not be zero
if ((float)$rating_request->Shipment->Package[$i]->PackageWeight->Weight <= 0)
{
    $rating_request->Shipment->Package[$i]->PackageWeight->Weight = '0.1';
}
```

Add this line directly after it:

```
// force weight to 50 lb
$rating_request->Shipment->Package[$i]->PackageWeight->Weight = 50;
```